# skip default column sorting option in datatables plugin

Tags: php, datatables

I have a list of records which are fetching from mysql database. I have to show those records along with **save csv** button, **search option**, **pagination** and **number of shows records in a page(10,25,50,100)**. For that I am trying to do by datatables plugin. But I dont want the column sort option as the sorting feature is manipulating from database according to the other criteria. 
Now is it possible to implement this scenario by datatables plugin? I have tried by the following code to skip the column sorting option.

```
"aoColumns": [
{ "bSortable": false },
{ "bSortable": false },
{ "bSortable": false },
{ "bSortable": false },
{ "bSortable": false },
{ "bSortable": false },
{ "bSortable": false },
{ "bSortable": false }
]
```

But here my application is sorting alphabetically based on the first column. Is there any option to hide the default sorting option also?

Please help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Turning off the sort will do it.

```
$(document).ready( function () {
     $('#example').dataTable( {
       "bSort": false
     } );
   } );
```

www.datatables.net/usage/features